# HTML update certain values via Java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I use ajax and have been trying to find a solution for a few days.
As you can see in the picture below, I already get a **Json** file in the console.
But I still can't manage to separate this and then display it in :

```
 <span ...>...</span>
```

That should be live data that is updated every second.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var intervalID = setInterval(update_values,1000);
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
function update_values()
{
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/update',
            function(data)
            {
                $('#update_data').getJSON
                console.log(data)
            });
};
</script>

...

<div class="card card-gray" id="card_bord1">
<h4>Board 1</h4>
<img src="../static/img/Rotary_Board_BW.png">
<p>Value: {{actuel_value_board1_html}}
    <span id="update_data">?</span>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("update_data").getE
    </script>
</p>
<label class="labelOFFLINE">Online</label>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: We can't really work with a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looks like this you need to "dig into" it.

```js
var dataJSON = [{
  "update_data": {
    '1': {
      "active_value": '1e+31',
      "is_active": false
    },
    '2': {
      "active_value": '5',
      "is_active": false
    }
  }
}]

setInterval(function() {
    // ajax call to data (I am using static json object above)
  data = dataJSON;
  
  
  // example one line drill-down
  console.log(data[0].update_data[1].is_active);

  // example "digging"
  console.log(data);
  data = data[0];
  console.log(data);
  data = data.update_data;
  console.log(data);
  data = data[1];
  console.log(data);
  data = data.is_active;
  console.log(data);

  var status = data ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
  $('.labelOFFLINE').html(status);
}, 1000);
```

All of this would be wrapped in a `setInterval()` function as shown above to poll every 1000ms (1 second).

https://jsfiddle.net/fu7Ld0x9/

Comment: Nice.
I Post my hole solution after. For the community.
I know i make a small formating mistake.
nice thank you.

Comment: Cool, I added the setInterval() function you'll need for polling that data every 1s